# Raspberry Pi Control Computer

Tags: networking, pi-2

I have Raspberry Pi 3 Model B V1.2
[image]

I'm trying to control a computer using my Pi. I have two computer. Both of them and my Pi connected to my ethernet modem. Lets say the Pi cant ping to computer A, it will automatically switch on computer B. My current plan is that i want to plug in cable to the pin that control the computer power off/on switch on the computer motherboard. I dont want to use the method wake-up on LAN method

Currently i have Piface Digital 2, PiFace Relay and 8ch SainSmart Relay. Which hardware should i go with in order to control the computer?

Comment: any of them should be fine, they are just relays.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The motherboard switch pins don't require huge amounts of voltage or current, as jet mentioned in the comments you should be fine with any of them. I'd go with either of the PiFaces as they'd have the best documentation for hooking up and programming. If you don't want to tie up a relay board, you would still be fine with some transistors and a breadboard, but it's up to you.